# What is this mirror hardware called?

Tags: hardware, mirror

One of the clip thingies that holds my bathroom mirror up broke, and I'd like to replace it.

It's the kind that works with a hole drilled through the mirror, though, not the clips, which are all I can find online.

[image: photo of clip]

Is there a specific name for this piece of hardware I can use to find it?

Comment: that is not a good picture, can we have more

Comment: More of a fancy holder/washer than a clip.  Made to spread the pressure of the screw over a wider area.

Comment: Excellent picture. I have exactly the same things on my hall bathroom mirror. (But not for sale...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have these (or very, very similar) on my hall bathroom mirror, probably ~ 65 years old. But it looks like they still make them, or something very similar, called a [Star Mirror Rosette](https://amzn.to/3Xpbb7i):

[image: Mirror Rosette]

This example is from Amazon in a large package (16!). Home Depot (and probably many other hardware and big box stores) have them in single packs for a couple dollars. Of course, most people probably need 4 - because if you just get 1 then it probably won't match the other 3. Most people probably don't need 16 - unless they are replacing mirrors in 4 bathrooms at once. So shop wherever it works best for you.

Comment: That is a 65 years old design. try something more modern.

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you!

Comment: @Ruskes I am interested if you know how to search for it -- I don't. :-)